# VBA Excel-How to remove duplicates based on three columns

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate rows based on three columns in a table in excel. 
When I pass the columns as direct values to an array say example columns 1, 61 and 122 it works fine like in the code below:

`cur.Range("data[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 61, 122), Header:=xlYes`

But when I try to pass column values in the array dynamically by finding their column number in the header, it neither throws any error nor removes the duplicates
below code is the dynamic one for passing the columns

`Set employeeCell = cur.Range("1:1").Find(What:="employee id")
    Set customerCell = cur.Range("1:1").Find(What:="customer")
    Set dateCell = cur.Range("1:1").Find(What:="date")

    cur.Range("data[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(employeecell.column,customercell.column, datecell.column), Header:=xlYes`

Kindly help on this. I want to remove duplicates based on three columns dynamically by finding their respective column numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`ListColumn.Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.index) of each column:

```
Dim dataTable as ListObject
Set dataTable = cur.ListObjects("data")

Dim employeeIndex as Long
employeeIndex = dataTable.ListColumns("employee id").Index

Dim customerIndex as Long
customerIndex = dataTable.ListColumns("customer").Index

Dim dateIndex as Long
dateIndex = dataTable.ListColumns("date").Index

dataTable.Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(employeeIndex, customerIndex, dateIndex), _
                                 Header:=xlYes
```